# Using regular paste (p) in normal mode breaks indentation - vim

Tags: indentation, copy-paste, vim

I saw that there is an `set paste` option that allows correct indentation when pasting from the system clipboard in terminal vim, but I miss how to paste from vim's buffer "inner clipboard" with the `p` or `P` command and apply `=` to the pasted text. Until now I manually do that.

Doing `set paste` or its inverse doesn't fix the indentation for the pasted text.

Could you help making a `.vimrc` mapping for it ? Or is there an built-in option for that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `]p` and `]P`

From `:help p`:

```
["x]]p              or                                  ]p ]<MiddleMouse>
["x]]<MiddleMouse>      Like "p", but adjust the indent to the current line.
                        Using the mouse only works when 'mouse' contains 'n'
                        or 'a'.  {not in Vi}

["x][P              or                                  [P
["x]]P              or                                  ]P
["x][p              or                                  [p [<MiddleMouse>
["x][<MiddleMouse>      Like "P", but adjust the indent to the current line.
                        Using the mouse only works when 'mouse' contains 'n'
                        or 'a'.  {not in Vi}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did look into `help p` but didn't scroll enough!

Answer (score 6):

The `]p` and `]P` commands will paste and place the contents at the indentation of the current line instead of using the original indentation of the copied lines. For example:

```
line 1
line 2
    line 3
    line 4
```

Copying lines 2 & 3, moving to line 3 and pressing `]p` would result in

```
line 1
line 2
    line 3
    line 2
        line 3
    line 4
```